# Can we integrate Sikuli and Selenium Web driver using Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I want to login using selenium web driver (in ruby) for windows authentication system, so i need sikuli integration to achieve login.
Is there any way to integrate

Comment: do you even google it ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install sikuli gem and also Sikuli IDE. And then require sikuli gem in the script in which you want to automate using Sikuli.

And write sikuli code to automate part you want to automate using Sikuli.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'sikuli'

screen = Sikuli::Screen.new

username = screen.click(<path_to_username_text_field_image_file>)
screen.type("username")

password = screen.click(<path_to_password_text_field_image_file>)
screen.type("password")

screen.click(<path_to_ok_button_image_file>)
```

Comment: Error: C:\Users\milin\Desktop\Kent>ruby "selenium and sikuli.rb"
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':
no such file to load -- C:\Sikuli-IDE-1.0.0-Win32/sikuli-script.jar (LoadError)

My code: require 'rubygems'
require 'Selenium-WebDriver'
require 'sikuli'


driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
screen = Sikuli::Screen.new
driver.get "http://test.com"
Username = Screen.click("1372055162772.png")
Screen.type("test)
Password = Screen.clickclick("1372055171683.png")
Screen.type("test")
Screen.click("1372055177395.png")

Comment: I have put selenium scrip and images in a folder and from there ia m accessing. also error showing "no such file to load" but sikuli-script.jar file is present in a folder

Comment: Follow steps mentioned http://rubydoc.info/gems/sikuli/0.3.0/frames and also require 'java' then it should work.

Comment: after following all steps, still getting error C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':
no such file to load -- java (LoadError)

Comment: code: require 'sikuli'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
screen = Sikuli::Screen.new
screen.click(10, 10)  ------upto this work fine,cursur navigates to x, y cordinate but
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox ------------nothing happened, script nither stop nor work